# mailchimp api, problem with dropped curl calls

Tags: php, mailchimp

I am using this library (https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api) for communicating with mailchimp api.
My problem is that when my code is running from the production server (centos), some api calls are failing. They return nothing at all (at method makeRequest in Mailchimp class, `$responseContent     = curl_exec($ch);` $responseContent is empty - no http error or error code). Same code from local ubundu is runining ok at the same time.

In my code i have to do 3 steps in order to create a campaign.

1. Create a segment in audience
2. Add email accounts in audience
3. Tag these accounts with the segment_id

I am not spamming the api. (i think at least)

Step 1 is one api call. Step 2 and 3 are using batch operations (each batch operation is limited to 400 ops). Even if i have to create a campaing for 50.000 email accounts, step 2 should make 125 batch calls max, plus api calls for batch check status. Each batch call is creating after the previus is finished. (batch op status is checking every 1 sec).

At this time, since i have problems, i am checking the code with only 2 email accounts.

Sometimes api calls are failing in step 1, sometimes in step 2 or 3. Moreover, after a failing operation,
api calls even for account info
`$api = new Mailchimp(); $api->get("")` are failing too for a sort period (about a minute)

Am i facing any rate limit problem? It is not clear in the docs.
Even if akamai firewall drop my calls, shouldn i have to get an error?
I have spent all day to get it work but problem is still there, even for a few calls. If it was a rate limit, when it resets?

Any other suggestion? thanks (sorry for my english - i did what i could)

Comment: Have you checked [`curl_getinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)? You will see more info about the connection, including http response etc, you might get some clues.

Comment: Yes, i did but it sounf anything useful ("url":"https:\/\/us15.api.mailchimp.com\/3.0\/\/templates?","content_type":null,"http_code":0,"header_size":0,"request_size":0,"filetime":-1,"ssl_verify_result":0,"redirect_count":0,"total_time":1.023969,"namelookup_time":3.5e-5,"connect_time":0,"pretransfer_time":0,"size_upload":0,"size_download":0,"speed_download":0,"speed_upload":0,"download_content_length":-1,"upload_content_length":-1,"starttransfer_time":0,"redirect_time":0,"redirect_url":""} and some info about target and local ips/ports.

Until this morning had these issues (empty calls) BUT..

Comment: At 08:00 UTC everything started to run smoothly. I even managed to create a campaign with 45.000 members...And after that the same again...It has to be a firewall issue i think but i posted question just in case that somebody has faced the same problem and found a solution...I am starting to thinking a setup that inludes a proxy server with 3-4 ip pool and using them for api calls to mailchimp api..Besides that, i do not have anything else in my mind..

Comment: At the first comment, i wanted to say that i didnt find anything usefull with curl_info